# How can I restore a Google apps user's documents?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, delete

I had to delete a Google apps user, and during the process deleted all the documents it owned.

I guess I can not restore that but is there a backup on Google servers anywhere?

Is there another way to restore these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: When a user is deleted, it can still be restored, as well as all the documents it owned for 30 days.

Go to the manage panel, and on the Organizations & users select the list: Recently deleted users.

[image]

You can restore the user as long as it's shown here.